# Sales Tax Total and % is known what is the cost of goods.

Tags: percentages

My question is. 
The sale tax  is 8.6 % the total cost of the item including sales tax  is $ 65.61.  What is the formula  to find the cost of the actual item ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I'm interpreting this is 
 $Cost of Item + Sales Tax = 65.51$. 
 
In that case, all you represent the original cost of the item as $x$. Therefore 
 
$x + x*SalesTax = TotalCost$.
 
 So all you need to do is turn the percentage into a decimal. 8.6% = .086.
 Which gives you $x +.086*x = 65.61$ This simplifies to $1.086x = 65.61$ or $x = 60.41$. The simpler formula is just that 
$Orginal Cost / (1 + SalesTax) = Orginal Cost$
 or $65.61 / 1.086 = OrginalCost$ which again is $60.41.

Comment: thank you... this is solved now..

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is the cost of the item, then the cost plus tax is

$$x + 0.086x = x(1.086).$$

That should be equal to the final cost, so

$$x(1.086) = 65.61.$$

If $r$ is the tax rate, then you have $(1+r)\mbox{cost} = \mbox{final}.$